# Magento Integrate html page in Product view page

Tags: magento

I have one html page which i got from designer, a typical html page.. that I want to call on specific action through controller.

The page having multiple self executable blocks like product view in middle, order summary in right side..etc

I want to know the best approach to integrate this html page in magento.

Till now I have created theme and create layout.xml.

Let me know suggestion.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What kind of "self executable blocks" do you have? are they written in PHP or JavaScript? Where do those blocks get their content-data from? Do you want to create a full Magento for all processing steps (catalog, customer, checkout, sale, etc.)? or do you just want to link-to this separate HTML page?

Comment: self executable blocks is a PHP code like getting products,add to cart button,see the checkout summary,buttons like.. in short I have a page with products listing, add cart and checkout summary in One page..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display HTML content on any page is using Static Block. From admin, create a static block with that HTML content and call that static block into any phtml file at your desire position.

Calling Static Block code:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('STATIC_BLOCK_IDENTIFIER')->toHtml();
```

Hope will help!